# Find using file for folder locations Linux Bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, find

I am trying to use a txt file to store folder locations to use in find command. But keep getting folder not found works with only one folder location in file

with  "$addfolder"

```
found=$(find "$addfolder" ! -path "*/.bak/*" -type f -iname "*$ffind*" | sort)
```

and replacing \"

```
addfolder="$addfolder $Folder"
```

folder.txt :-
Main/Public
Main/General
Not Used
Old Backup Files

```
#!/bin/bash 
addfolder=""    
filename="Settings/folders.txt"

#Read Folder.txt for locations
while read -r Folder; do
 if [ ! "$Folder" == "" ];then
  if [ -d "$Folder" ]; then
   addfolder="$addfolder \"$Folder\""
   echo "$addfolder"
  fi
fi
done < "$filename"

if [  "$addfolder" == "" ]; then
 exit
fi

echo -e "\e[36mEnter Filename To Find :-\e[0m"
read -p "" ffind
echo -e "\e[92mSearching:\e[0m"
found=$(find $addfolder ! -path "*/.bak/*" -type f -iname "*$ffind*" | sort)

echo -e "\e[33m$found\e[0m"
echo "Press Enter To Exit"
read -s -n 1 -p ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular variables should only hold single strings.

To hold lists of strings, use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash 
addfolder=()    
filename="Settings/folders.txt"

#Read Folder.txt for locations
while IFS= read -r Folder; do
 if [ ! "$Folder" == "" ];then
  if [ -d "$Folder" ]; then
   addfolder+=( "$Folder" )
   echo "${addfolder[@]}"
  fi
fi
done < "$filename"

if [  "${#addfolder[@]}" == 0 ]; then
 exit
fi

echo -e "\e[36mEnter Filename To Find :-\e[0m"
read -p "" ffind
echo -e "\e[92mSearching:\e[0m"
found=$(find "${addfolder[@]}" ! -path "*/.bak/*" -type f -iname "*$ffind*" | sort)

echo -e "\e[33m$found\e[0m"
echo "Press Enter To Exit"
read -s -n 1 -p ""
```

Comment: @theotherguy Same should go for `found=$(find "${addfolder[@]}" ! -path "*/.bak/*" -type f -iname "*$ffind*" | sort)`